# Is it possible to give an entity-name target for a @ManyToOne join

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I am attempting to use hibernate annotations in a project in which hbm.xml files are the norm. What I am finding though is that there are some major limitations when attempting to use both hbm and annotation conventions in the same project. Now the question is whether or not I can specify an entity name for a class with annotations when attempting to join with another class?

The problem broken down is that when the context is being created by hibernate, the entity name specified in the hbm file is something like "Person", but when the annotation class is being brought into the context it is trying to look up "com.this.is.classpath.Person" when it is attempting to resolve the dependent class. Is there a way that I can instruct to look for the custom entity-name rather than the classpath?

I have already attempted to change the entity name of the Person in the hbm file to the classpath, but that has caused a number of issues throughout the project.

Annotation entity:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "Group")
public class Group implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Column(insertable = false)
    private Long id;

    @IgnoreSizeOf
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "createdBy", referencedColumnName = "PersonId")
    private Person createdBy;
}
```

old hbm mapping for the Person class:

```
<hibernate-mapping package="com.this.is.classpath" default-cascade="save-update, persist, merge, lock, replicate, evict, refresh" default-access="field">
    <class name="Person" entity-name="Person" table="Person" dynamic-update="true" optimistic-lock="none" lazy="true" discriminator-value="1">
```

When the hibernate context is being constructed it results in this output.

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.AnnotationException: @OneToOne or @ManyToOne on com.this.is.classpath.Group.createdBy references an unknown entity: com.this.is.classpath.Person
```

I have debugged the hibernate code and discovered that it is attempting to use the Person's classpath as the entity-name in the context rather than the described "Person" entity-name from the hbm file.

Comment: I don't understand your question. The entity name is Person in any case and has nothing to do with the fully qualified classname

Comment: The problem is that the annotated entity is only trying to refer to the hbm entity by its qualified classname as its entity-name rather than the entity-name that is defined in the hbm file.